# getdate() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I display only date while using `getdate()` function?

When I am using

```
select getdate() as Today's Date
```

It is giving me:

```
2016-05-18 08:32:07.100
```

But I only need:

```
 2016-05-18
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use convert. The first argument truncates the length, and the last specifies the format you want the date in:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 103) as [Today's Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, you may also want to look at `FORMAT` - which in my opinion is a bit nicer to read/use.

Example: `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')`

See [this msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213505.aspx) for more info